# Roll back an edit mistake

Tags: support, editing

I made an edit to an old question, [Bottom bracket bearing Issues](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/9882/bottom-bracket-bearing-issues), which had been bumped by someone posting a new answer.

I changed the OP words "non lockring side" to "non drive side"; I meant to change the wording to "drive side" but forgot to delete the 'non'.

I think I made a material change to the question, in error, but my efforts to correct the mistake have been blocked by the review process. I put in two edits to correct the mistake and don't want to continue doing that. I know it's an old question but it's still important to me that I leave the question how it should be.

What can we do about correcting the mistake I made?

Comment: Fixed - I guess there's a chance the Italian BB he's looking at had a lockring on the drive/crank side, (it is Italian !)

Comment: @Criggie thanks, for sure I can't rule it out either!